# Dijkstra's Algo Implementation using STL

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, stl, dijkstra

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long
vector<pair<ll,ll> >v[100005];
ll dis[100005];
bool visited[100005];
multiset<pair <ll,ll> > s;
int main(){
    ll n,m,from,next,weight,i;
    cin>>n>>m;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        v[i].clear();
        dis[i]=2e9;
    }
    for(i=1;i<=m;i++){
        cin>>from>>next>>weight;
        v[from].push_back(make_pair(next,weight));
        v[next].push_back(make_pair(from,weight));
    }
    dis[1]=0;
    s.insert({0,1});
    memset(visited,false,sizeof(visited));
    while(!s.empty()){
        pair<ll,ll>p= *s.begin();
        s.erase(s.begin());
        ll x=p.second;
        ll wei=p.first;
        if(visited[x]) continue;
        for(i=0;i<v[x].size();i++){
            ll e=v[x][i].first;
            ll w=v[x][i].second;
            if(dis[x]+w < dis[e]){
                dis[e]=dis[x]+w;
                s.insert({dis[e],e});
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=2;i<=m;i++)
     cout<<dis[i]<<" ";
}
```

I have a c++ implementation of Dijkstra's Algo, but I guess this is not working properly for all cases(larger test cases). Can anyone help me fixing this. Have I missed something or not proeprly implemented.
The code output the min distances of each vertices from the source vertex(i.e. 1).

Comment: This is an awesomely bad idea: [`#include<bits/stdc++.h>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) [`using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Together they do two things: 1. Pull the entire standard library into the global namespace leaving you with an amazing minefield of naming collisions and silent substitutions and 2. get your resume and portfolio tossed into the roundfile. Just don't do this.

Comment: On a more immediately useful front, please provide a set of inputs that makes your implementation fail. Makes debugging easier. If that's a no go because of immense size, consider using the debugger that almost certainly came with your debugger.

Comment: you didn't change visited for source node. Source node should be marked as visited before entering the while loop.

Comment: @user4581301 That's just useless advice. Literally everybody does that in competitive programming, even some of the most experienced people working at big companies. You're optimizing the number of keystrokes there.

Comment: If you want proper code review you might want to go on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, this is more suited for this type of questions

Comment: @Zouch CR.SE is for working code

Comment: The OP does not seem sure it's code is not working, so I guess it is working in some / most cases. Having a proper review might help pointing out some errors.

Answer (score 1):

You never write to the `visited` array. Hence edges might be scanned multiple times. Simple fix: Add a single line after the `if(visited[x]) continue;`:

```
visited[x] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to solve in O(N) the graphs: 
           #include 
        #include 
        #include

```
     typedef long long ll;
    void fs_int(int *x) {
        register int c = getchar_unlocked();
        *x = 0;
        int neg = 0;

        for(; ((c<48 || c>57) && c != '-'); c = getchar_unlocked());

        if(c=='-') {
            neg = 1;
            c = getchar_unlocked();
        }

        for(; c>47 && c<58 ; c = getchar_unlocked()) {
            *x = (*x<<1) + (*x<<3) + c - 48;
        }

        if(neg)
            *x = -(*x);
    } 
    typedef struct {
        int next;
        int val;
        int d;

    }List;
    typedef struct 
    {
        int parent;
        int shrt;
        ll count;
        int on_reg;
        int ch;
    } Node;
    #define MOD 1000000007
    ll get_sum(Node *tr,List *l)
    {
        Node *t, *t2;
        int i,j,n=0,fix;
        ll result;
        static int *reg=NULL,sz=1000;

        if (!reg)
            reg=malloc(sizeof(int)*sz);
        reg[n++]=1;
        int  cur_d;

        while(n)
        {
            ///fix is the limit for the for, it is the shortname of "for ix" :
            // from 0 to fix there are the old values, from fix to n there are the new ones
            fix=n;   
            for (i=0;i<fix;i++)
            {

               //the better way to reduce the complexity is shift the last item to the current one
                t=&tr[reg[i]];
                reg[i--]=reg[--fix];
                reg[fix]=reg[--n];
                t->on_reg=0;

                ///this scores all the edges from departing from this node
                ///the criteria to avoid propagation is the key of the program
                for (j=t->ch;j;j=l[j].next)
                {   
                    if (l[j].val==1) //avoid the root
                        continue;

                    t2=&tr[l[j].val]; //store in some comfortable variable

                    cur_d=t->shrt+l[j].d; 

                    if (t2->shrt!=0 && t2->shrt< cur_d ) ///if my path is heaviest nothing to do
                        continue;
                    else if (t2->shrt ==cur_d) //I found an item with same weight. It was required to count them
                        t2->count++;
                    else if (t2->shrt==0 || t2->shrt>cur_d) //found a unexplored item or my path is lighter
                    {
                        t2->shrt=cur_d;
                        t2->count=1;
                        if (!t2->on_reg) //if not already in the reg, I insert it inside
                        {
                            if (n>=sz)
                            {
                                sz<<=1;
                                reg=realloc(reg, sizeof(int)*sz);
                            }
                            reg[n++]=l[j].val; //at position n
                            t2->on_reg=1;
                        }
                    }

                }
           /* printf ("reg: ");
            for (k=0;k<n;k++)
                printf ("%d ",reg[k]);
                printf ("\n");*/
            }
        }

        //printf ("\n");
        return result;


    }

    typedef long long ll;
    void set_depth(Node *tr, List *l, int rt,int cd,int parent)
    {
        int i;

        tr[rt].parent=parent;
        for (i=tr[rt].ch;i;i=l[i].next)
            if (l[i].val== parent )
                continue;
            else 
                set_depth(tr,l,l[i].val,cd+1,rt);
    }

    int main ()
    {

        int t,n,q,i,u,v,d;
        fs_int(&t);
        int il=1;
        Node tr[100005];
        List l[200005];
        List *tl;
        while (t--)
        {
            fs_int(&n);
            fs_int(&q);
            il=1;

            memset(tr,0,sizeof(tr));
            memset(l,0,sizeof(l));

            for (i=0;i<q;i++)
            {
                fs_int(&u);
                fs_int(&v);
                fs_int(&d);

                tl=&l[il];
                tl->next=tr[u].ch;
                tl->val=v;
                tl->d=d;
                tr[u].ch=il++;


                tl=&l[il];
                tl->next=tr[v].ch;
                tl->val=u;
                tl->d=d;
                tr[v].ch=il++;

            }

           //set_depth(tr,l,1,0,0);
           // print(tr,l,1,0,0);

           get_sum(tr,l);

           ll res=1;
            for (i=2;i<=n;i++)
            {


                res= ( (res%MOD) *(tr[i].count%MOD) )%MOD;
            }   
            printf ("%lld\n",res);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

the function that interests you is the function get_sum(). It is a breadth first search, that in a graph means check along concentric circles, that allows you to avoid useless propagations. It store the values in this virtual circle, on an array, called reg. And at each step you are going to check forward. About the efficency you can check by your self at   [Ways](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/shortest-path-algorithms/practice-problems/algorithm/ways/) contest. It has one of the best time